# C - What does this comma separated declaration mean

Tags: c, syntax

Apologies for the silly question, but I don't know how to find a reference for this. I found some code for a TCP server and this line is confusing me:

`int master_sockfd, client_sockfds[3] = {0}, cli_sockfd, client_games_started[3];`

None of the variables above have been initialized beforehand so it looks like it's being declared here. Can someone help me understand what this is saying? If I recall correctly `{0}` sets `int` to 0 but I can't understand it in this context. I'm also very confused on how there looks to be two declarations with three assignments. And yes, everything compiled without errors/warnings. Thanks!

Comment: Take care when doing this with pointer variables.  `int* a, b, c;` is a pointer and 2 ints, whereas `int *a, *b, *c;` is 3 pointers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
int master_sockfd, client_sockfds[3] = {0}, cli_sockfd, client_games_started[3];
```

is identical to:

```
int master_sockfd;
int client_sockfds[3] = {0};
int cli_sockfd;
int client_games_started[3];
```

- `master_sockfd` and `cli_sockfd` are integers
- `client_sockfds` is an array of 3 integers, all initialized to zero
- `client_games_started` is an array of 3 integers

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Could you elaborate more on how exactly I should parse this? eg why exactly did `cli_sockfd` and `client_games_started[3]` get initialized like that when it's on the rhs?

Comment: Oh nvm, I see. I was parsing it wrong. The syntax is essentially `int a,(b=c),d,e;`

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence : note that comma operator has lowest priority of all operators. See also https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Built-in_comma_operator

Comment: @Bktero Except operator precedence doesn't apply, because neither the `=` nor the `,` are used as operators here. The comma `,` separates declarators in a declaration, and the `=` introduces the initializer which is an optional part of one declarator.